# Clicking on a div tag

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I am using WWW::Scripter to grab a page written with javascript/ajax, the "link" to the next page is a div tag, I can get the tag but cannot seem to figure out a way to click on it to get to the next page.. Any suggestions?

```
my $w = new WWW::Scripter;
$w->use_plugin('Ajax'); 
$w->get($c->website);

my $loop = 1;
my $page = 1;

while ($loop) {
  my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
  $content = $w->content();

  $te->parse($content);
  $table = $te->first_table_found;
  $str .= Dumper $table;
  $page += 1;

  $loop = $self->next_page($w);
}

sub next_page {
my $self = shift;
my $w = shift;
$div = $w->document->getElementById('example_next');
if (defined $div) {
--I want to click on the div and move to the next page, suggestions?---
return 1;
} else {
return 0;
}
}
```

example html code... First there is a table holding the data...

```
 <table class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    headers
</thead>
<tbody>---DATA---</tbody>
 </table>
```

Then pagination to go from "page" to "page" the data is rewritten with each pagination click..

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_two_button" id="example_paginate">
<div class="paginate_disabled_previous" title="Previous" id="example_previous"></div>
<div class="paginate_enabled_next" title="Next" id="example_next"></div>
</div>
```

This is all using www.datatables.net

Comment: Websites cannot be written in JavaScript or AJAX. AJAX is a technology and JS is a client-side scripting language. A `<div>`-Tag cannot be a link. It might have an `onclick`-event in JS. Please show somoe of the HTML of the website you are trying to automate or we cannot help you.

Comment: the page is "written" using jquery datatables... the <div> is the "link" to the next page..  <div class="paginate_enabled_next" title="Next" id="example_next"></div> there is a large amount of js on the page.. when I did this script using IEAutomation it worked but I was having trouble IEAutomation and OLE errors so I wanted to use something different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the JavaScript call that occurs when that div's id is clicked, and then execute it. Alternatively you could use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox or WWW::Selenium.